# JSON support for mysql with go-grom

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I'm trying to use the native JSON support introduced in MySQL 5.7.8

Below is a quick sample app I'm trying out.

DB Schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `experiment` (
 `id`              INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name`            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `age`             INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 10,
 `content`         JSON NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

GO code

```
package main

import (
  "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
  _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"
  "encoding/json"
)

type Experiment struct {
 gorm.Model
 Name    string `json:"name"`
 Age     int64  `json:"age"`
 Content map[string]interface{} `json:"content"`
}

func main() {
   db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", "root:root@/testdb?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local")
   if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
   }
  defer db.Close()
  j1 := []byte(`{"name":"anu", "age": 123, "content": { "k1" : "v1",  "k2" : [1,2,3]}}`)

    var ex Experiment
   json.Unmarshal(j1, &ex)
   // Create
  db.Create(&ex)
}
```

Here Experiment.Content values are unpredictable. I have to use a generic map for that reasons.

However This program throws the following error
`(sql: converting Exec argument $6 type: unsupported type map[string]interface {}, a map)`

Is this not supported yet with the go-gorm library. What's the best way to achieve both read and write for this json content?

Comment: It's going to map your fields to columns in the database. How would you go about shoving a map into one column?

Comment: I know this is for postgres but it might help? http://www.booneputney.com/development/gorm-golang-jsonb-value-copy/

Comment: @Gavin I've added the DB schema to the question. Question is whether the ORM would support that. Of course I can convert it to a string field, problem with that is; it's gonna be too costly in a case where I need to read a list of entries.